# Find a topology $\mathscr{T}_0$ for which $f,g : ( \mathbb{R}^2, \mathscr{T}_0) → (\mathbb{R}^2, \mathscr{T}_{R}^{c} )$ is continuous.

Tags: general-topology, continuity

For $f,g : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$, define:

$$ x \rightarrow f(x) := \begin{cases}
x^2 & \text{for }x \le 1 \\
x+1 & \text{for }x > 1
\end{cases}
$$

$$ x \rightarrow g(x) := \begin{cases}
x^3 
\end{cases}
$$
Where $\mathscr{T}_{R}^{c}$ is the Euclidean topology on $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$

I know that 
$\tau_0$ will be the initial topology with respect to $f$ and $g$. The second topology is still Euclidean the basis for which is open sets of the form $(a,b) \times (c,d)$, $a,b,c,d  \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a \le b$ and $c \le d$. Could I get a hint on how to proceed?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: You can take the initial topology, yes. So you have to consider what the inverse image of different open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ are under $f$ and $g$. I think taking the product topology of the weak topology on $\mathbb{R}$ w.r.t. $f$ and the usual topology on the second factor will do.

Comment: I suggest adding "the *coarsest* topology". Otherwise some wise-guy like me will come in and say "the discrete topology" :)

Comment: By inverse, do you mean the pre-image?

Comment: @user207114: Yes, *inverse image under* $f$ and *pre-image under* $f$ are synonyms.